# unable to create user with REST api email

Tags: rest-api, java

Hi I am using REST API to create new USER, when i am extracting the meta data using the

/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/User/describe

the label for 'Email' field is shown as 'E-mail' whereas on salesforce GUI it is 'Email' and the corresponding name for it is given as 'Email'

when i am executing the request i am getting a 'Bad Request' 400 error.

Please help

My code for building http request is

```
        public void createUser()
        {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String json = "{ \"LastName\" : \"kumar\" , \"Alias\" : \"Shal\", \"Email\": \"shal@xyz.com\", \"Username\" : \"shailesh\" , \"CommunityNickname\" : \"shailesh\"}";

        StringEntity sentity = new StringEntity(json);
        sentity.setContentType("application/json");

        String query1 = "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/User/";
        HttpPost get1 = new HttpPost(environment + query1);
        get1.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
        get1.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        get1.setEntity(sentity);

        HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(get1);
        System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        }
```

i am able to create new Account and Contact using the same function but when i am creating the Users i am getting Bad Request so my JSON must only be wrong.

Comment: post your actual api request.

Comment: Hi @superfell i have edited the question, i think my JSON is wrong but i am unable to findout what it is. can you please help me.

Comment: Have you got spare user licences on your org? Is the email address unique (shal@xyz.com has not been created as a user in any other org)?

Comment: Hi @DougB yes the email id shal@xyz.com is unique, and yes i have spare user licences (i am new to Salesforce and i have a developer edition account, i have created only one user so i guess i have more user licences, please correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: The response body will have more details on what's wrong with the request, looks like you're missing some additional required fields.

Comment: hi @superfell the response has a 404 code and a Bad Request message I have updated my json to- {\"LastName\" : \"akia\", \"Alias\" : \"vala\", \"Email\" : \"shailesh.p@xyz.com\", \"Username\" : \"shal@xyz.com\", \"CommunityNickname\" : \"shal\", \"EmailEncodingKey\" : \"UTF-8\", \"DigestFrequency\" : \"D\", \"DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency\" : \"N\" ,\"UserRoleId\" : \"00E90000001254ZEAQ\", \"LanguageLocaleKey\" : \"en_US\", \"LocaleSidKey\" : \"en_IN\", \"TimeZoneSidKey\" : \"Asia/Calcutta\" ,\"UserType\": \"Standard\"}